# How to upload an image to apollo-server from apollo-angular using graphql-codegen?

Tags: angular, file-upload, graphql, apollo-server, apollo-angular

This is my receiver in the server.

```
 
  @Mutation(() => String)
  async register(
    @Arg("picture", () => GraphQLUpload) { createReadStream, filename }: any
  ): Promise<string> {
    console.log(__dirname);
    try {
      const promise = await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) =>
        createReadStream()
          .pipe(createWriteStream(__dirname + `/../../../images/${filename}`))
          .on("finish", () => resolve(true))
          .on("error", () => reject(false))
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    return "";
  }
```

---

This is my raw  `register.graphql` which is later compiled using graphql-codegen.

```
mutation Register($picture: Upload!) {
  register(picture:$picture)
}
```

---

I am stuck on the angular part. So far I have this.

```
  uploadClicked($event: any) {
    let file = $event.target.files[0];
    console.log(file);
    this.registerGQL.mutate({ picture: { file } }).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
```

This is my error when I try to submit it.
[image]

Comment: FromData is used for 'manual' querying (using axios/fetch) - apollo client processes (should) it internally, simply try to pass a `file` as `picture` variable

Comment: @xadm I'm still getting the same errors 

---

```let file = $event.target.files[0];
    console.log(file);
    this.registerGQL.mutate({ picture: file }).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    }); ```

Comment: API tested separately (postman/insomnia)? is network request properly formatted (graphql upload specs)?

Comment: @xadm Yes the API works perfectly with postman. Its just the angular part I'm confused in.

Comment: network request? I don't know A. ... follow some angular upload tutorial for required config ... adapt until it works (request) according to specs

Comment: @xadm Am I supposed to do ```this.registerGQL.mutate({ picture: { file } })``` or ```this.registerGQL.mutate({ picture: file  })```?

Comment: you already tested both! rather 2nd one ... still search for proper client config/requirements .. EOT